# Integrating WCS and SSFS through WID

Tags: java, wcs

While importing the Mediation Module into Websphere Integration Developer, it shows an error stating "XMLDataHandler cannot be resolved". It seems that the mediation module is missing out the com.ibm.wbiserver.datahandler.xml.XMLDataHandler package. The error message is given as below:

> CWSCA8070E: The class RemoveNamespaceFromXMLDataHandler [in
>   RemoveNamespaceFromXMLDataHandler.java [in
>   com.ibm.commerce.sample.mediation.util [in  [in
>   WCToSSFSMediationModule]]]]   long serialVersionUID   Logger logger
>   RemoveNamespaceFromXMLDataHandler()   Object transform(Object, Class,
>   Object)   void transformInto(Object, Object, Object)   void
>   setBindingContext(Map) data binding type does not implement the
>   com.ibm.websphere.sca.jms.data.JMSDataBinding
>   interface.    SSFSAPIsExport.export   WCToSSFSMediationModule line 1  SCDL
>   Validation Marker
>
> The import com.ibm.wbiserver cannot be
>   resolved  RemoveNamespaceFromXMLDataHandler.java  WCToSSFSMediationModule/com/ibm/commerce/sample/mediation/util  line
>   47    Java Problem
>
> XMLDataHandler cannot be resolved to a
>   type  RemoveNamespaceFromXMLDataHandler.java  WCToSSFSMediationModule/com/ibm/commerce/sample/mediation/util  line 50 Java Problem
>
> The method transform(Object, Class, Object) of type
>   RemoveNamespaceFromXMLDataHandler must override or implement a
>   supertype
>   method    RemoveNamespaceFromXMLDataHandler.java  WCToSSFSMediationModule/com/ibm/commerce/sample/mediation/util  line
>   63    Java Problem

Due to this error, I am unable to export the project and deploy it in the application server. i am unable to download the right jar, which contains the required java package com.ibm.wbiserver.datahandler.xml.XMLDataHandler". 
Please help me on this error, as I am not sure what to do with this.

Comment: can anyone please help me on this !!

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is quite late, but still want to post it.
The XMLDataHandler could be found in the lib of com.ibm.ws.bpm.redist.commonj.connector.jar
And this jar file is located at the plugins folder of server runtime